# What is the length of module $M/(M_1\cap M_2 \cap \cdots\cap M_n)$ given $M/M_i$ has finite length?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I've met a problem in my algebra exercises.

> Let $M_1,M_2,\ldots,M_n$ be submodules of $M$ such that each $M/M_i$ has finite length. Prove that $M/(M_1\cap M_2 \cap \cdots\cap M_n)$ has finite length. Moreover, determine a formula for computing this length.

I've tried some examples for this. 
Let
$$
M=\mathbb{Z},M_1=4\mathbb{Z},M_2=9\mathbb{Z},M_3=6\mathbb{Z}
$$
Denote $c(M)$ be the length of module $M$.
We have,
$$
c(M/M_1)=c(M/M_2)=c(M/M_3)=2
$$
$$
c(M/(M_1\cap M_2))=4,c(M/(M_1\cap M_3))=3
$$

It seems that it should be the $\sum_{i=1}^nc(M/M_i)$ minus something showing the relations between $M_i$. But I cant figure it out.

Can you please help? Thank you!

EDIT:
A summary of the answer:
Thanks to Georges Elencwajg's help, the formula should be:
$$
\begin{align*}
\phantom{=}&c(M/(M_1\cap M_2 \cap \cdots\cap M_n))\\
&=c(M/M_1)+\cdots+c(M/M_n)\\
&\quad{}-(c(M/(M_1+M_2))+c(M/(M_1+M_3))+\cdots+c(M/(M_{n-1}+M_n)))\\
&\quad{}+(c(M/(M_1+M_2+M_3))+\cdots+c(M/(M_{n-2}+M_{n-1}+M_n)))\\
&\qquad{}\vdots\\
&\quad{}+(-1)^{n-1}c(M/(M_1+\cdots+M_n))


\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You are on the right track.  The formula for the length is along the lines of inclusion-exclusion, using the lengths of those quotients by intersections as the ingredients.  Such a formula will only prove finite length with a strong induction, since you'll need to know all the smaller intersections are also finite length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a reminder

> **Key result on finite-length modules**
>   Given a short exact sequence of  modules $0\to N'\to N\to N''\to 0$, one has  the equivalence 
>   $$N \text{ has finite length } \iff       N'\text{ and } N'' \text{ have finite length }  $$ 
>   and if this is the case 
>   $$\text{ length } (N)=    \text{ length } (N')+\text{ length } (N'')        $$

And now, back to your question. Consider the exact sequence
$  0\to M_1/M_1\cap M_2 \to  M/M_2  $
The implication  $\Rightarrow$ tells you that  $M_1/M_1\cap M_2$ has finite length,  since  by assumption$M/M_2$ has finite length.

Now contemplate the exact sequence
$0\to M_1/M_1\cap M_2 \to  M/M_1\cap M_2  \to M/M_1 \to 0$.
Since we just proved that the leftmost  module has finite length and since the rightmost module  has finite length by assumption , the implication  $\Leftarrow$ of the key result tells us that the middle module   $M/M_1 \cap M_2$ has finite length:  we have just proved the case $n=2$ of the question.
A trivial induction yields the general case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried to deduce the length formula from your result, getting that $c(M/(M_1\cap M_2))=c(M/M_1)+c(M/M_2)-c(M/(M_1+M_2)). However, I  got stuck when I tried to generalize it for $n>2$. (I want to find a formula symmetric in $M_i$)

Comment: Ah…Now I think I've worked the formula out and it just looks like inclusion-exclusion principle, as Jack Schmidt commented. I'll post it here later. Thanks again!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: You've shown that $lngt\frac{M}{A\cap B}=lngt\frac{M}{A}+lngt\frac{M}{B}-lngt\frac{M}{A\cap B}$. How is the induction trivial? Taking $A=M_1$ and $B=M_2\cap\ldots\cap M_n$, the obtained formula includes $lngt\frac{M}{A_1+A_2\cap\ldots\cap A_n}$, which I don't know how to handle.